# Poor performance on View

Tags: sql-server-2008

Overall challenge:

We are adding items to a table several times a day for a number of "markets".

So

- at 12:00 we add 2000 items for market "x"
- at 12:30 we add 3000 items for market "y"
- at 14:00 we add 2500 items for market "x" again

This is done several times each day.

At any given time we need to extract the latest items for each market for each day

The desired result for the above insertions is

2500 items for market "x"

3000 items for market "y"

Each addition of a batch of data has an ExecutionTime timestamp that defines the batch uniquely. So the 2000 items for market "x" at 12:00 will have the same ExecutionTime value and the 2500 items for market "x" at 14:00 will have another ExecutionTime value.

We have created a view doing this for us as

```
SELECT     
    *
FROM         
    dbo.Items AS s
WHERE     
    (ExecutionTime =
       (SELECT     MAX(ExecutionTime) AS Expr1
        FROM          dbo.Items AS s2
        WHERE      (SiteAlias = s.SiteAlias) AND (Market = s.Market) 
          AND (LocalTimestamp >= 
            DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, s.LocalTimestamp), 0)) 
          AND 
              (LocalTimestamp < 
            DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, s.LocalTimestamp), 1))))
```

We query the view like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [ExportedData]
WHERE 
  SiteAlias = 'MyAlias'
  AND LocalTimeStamp between '2012-05-14 00:00' AND '2012-05-18 00:00'
ORDER BY [Timestamp]
```

We have defined indexes on the table ITems on the fields Execution time and a combined index on sitealias, marked and localtimestamp.

Problem: the performance sucks. It takes several minutes to query about 150000 rows.

Are there any obvious improvements to the view we should do? I am ready to supply queryplans etc - in case there is no simple screwup we did in creating the view.

An interesting thing is that if we query the view with "LIKE" on the SiteAlias instead of "=", it speeds up the execution with about 90% - which I did not expect.

Thanks,

:o)

/Jesper
Copenhagen

Comment: What kind of indices do you have on the underlying table `Items` ??

Comment: Execution plan of view query would help.

Comment: @marc_s The indexes defined on the underlying Items table are

a non-clustered index on the field Execution time

a combined, non-clustered index on fields sitealias, marked and localtimestamp.

Comment: Seems sensible - have you looked at the execution plan for one of your queries against the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your T-SQL and table structure look fine to me at first glance - so this is just a wild shot into the dark :-)

What I would probably try in your position would be to use a CTE (common table expression) and casting `LocalTimestamp` to datatype `DATE` since you're on SQL Server 2008.

With those in place, you can have your view be something like:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourView
AS
   WITH DataPerDay AS
   (
      SELECT 
         *,
         RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(LocalTimestamp AS DATE) 
                                     ORDER BY ExecutionTime DESC)
      FROM         
         dbo.Items AS s
   )
   SELECT *
   FROM DataPerDay 
   WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Basically, the CTE "partitions" your data by the date-only part of `LocalTimestamp` and then assigns sequential numbers to all entries on that day, starting at 1 - so the "newest" or "most recent" entry per day gets `RowNum = 1` which is what I use in the select from that CTE.

This gets around the `SELECT(MAX) ....` subquery and seems to be a tad faster in my personal observation - but that's heavily dependant on your tables and data - so just try that for yourself and see if it helps!

Comment: I used your suggestion and after I managed to analyse my data to get the right "partition definition" (i.e. what defines a "partition" in my case?). The result is simply amazing. I partition my data in a view and query this view by joining my "master table" onto it. The net result is that the query on 150000 rows consistantly **takes less than a second to complete**. Thanks a lot for yor input :o)

Comment: @JesperLundStocholm: glad to have been able to provide input to help solve your issue! CTE's and ranking functions like `ROW_NUMBER` are definitely one of the rather under-used (and not so well known) features that SQL Server 2005 introduced...

Answer (score 2):

> *An interesting thing is that if we query the view with "LIKE" on the SiteAlias instead of "=", it speeds up the execution with about
>   90% - which I did not expect.*

Hm, that's indeed strange. This can be a consequence of the underlying problem.

Is the query consistently slow or does the perf problems start after a while.
Can you add OPTION (RECOMPILE) to the end of the query so that we can rule out "parameter sniffing"?

```
SELECT *
FROM [ExportedData]
WHERE 
  SiteAlias = 'MyAlias'
  AND LocalTimeStamp between '2012-05-14 00:00' AND '2012-05-18 00:00'
ORDER BY [Timestamp]
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

You are saying that the table is added to several times a day. SQL Server usually does an excellent job in keeping the statistics up to date but there can the possibility that the optimizer is using wrong/out of data statistics

- Is AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS set to on for this db?
- Can you isolate a slow performing instance of the query and let it run after refreshing all the statistics?

It would be good to see execution plans of the like and the = version of the query.

**Update 1**

You gave a screenshot of the estimated execution plan. We need to see the *actual* (which included the estimate).
Also, The second link to the screenshot does not work.

Can you update the question with the xml plans instead of putting them into the comments. This will also be more helpful to the new people taking a look at the question.

I don't get that the execution plan for the "=" version says the 100% goes into a Key lookup when the estimated number of rows is 1. That doesn't make sense

The xml plan of the actual execution can certainly help. You could take a look at the difference between actual and estimated number of rows since the cardinality may be off.
Using temp tables in this case may help since statistics are accurate and you can lay indexes on it

```
SELECT *
into #tempExportedData
FROM [ExportedData]

SELECT *
FROM #tempExportedData
WHERE 
  SiteAlias = 'MyAlias'
  AND LocalTimeStamp between '2012-05-14 00:00' AND '2012-05-18 00:00'
ORDER BY [Timestamp]
```

Comment: I read from your comments that you have a combined, non-clustered index on fields sitealias, marked and localtimestamp. You are aware that the order you specify the columns is important right? Only if localtimestamp is the first column the optimizer will consider using it

Comment: The execution plan for equals (visual representation of it) can be found here: http://imgur.com/CmTmi (so you need the XML-version of it?). The execution plan for "LIKE" can bee seen here: http://imgur.com/5rPFB

I have added the OPTION (RECOMPILE) and it did not make a difference. Altso the AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS is set on the DB.

I have tried to run the query after updating statictics with sp_updatestats and had no effect

Comment: @JesperLundStocholm On 2008 running `SELECT * FROM master..spt_values WHERE name = 'rpc'` and `SELECT * FROM master..spt_values WHERE name LIKE 'rpc'` gives estimated rows of `1` vs `18.563` so seems that it uses a different method for calculating cardinality estimates for some reason which is presumably why you get a different plan.

Comment: On 2005 the numbers are `1` vs `1.84724`

Comment: @Jesper Did you make any progress? I updated my answer with some new suggestions. Also, if its possible to remote desktop It can increase the chance of a quick solution but I guess that isn't possible

Comment: @buckley Yes I did. I used the suggestion from marc_s and it solved my problems. I still have no idea of why the query-plan of the previous attempts were to crazy - I'll cross that bridge again if I it returns. Thanks for your suggestions!